# Как установить SDKmanager на linux mint 19?

Tags: android, sdk

Сегодня заинтересовался Android разработкой. Уже пользовался QT(недолго). Решил юзать его. Захожу в раздел андроид - требует установленный sdk. Для полной установки требуется SDKmanager, которого у меня нет. Искал способы его скачать, не получается.

```
sdkmanager: command not found
```

Помогите (

Answer (score 0):

при скачивании android studio в zip есть android sdk. Но при желании вы, конечно, можете его скачать вручную с страницы https://developer.android.com/studio/ (внизу страницы)

В android studio изменить путь до sdk можно в настройках[image: введите сюда описание изображения]